# Machine Learning for Image segmentation vs location identification

Tags: image-segmentation, machine-learning

There are several machine learning architectures specifically devoted to image segmentation (like [UNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-Net)).

I am interested on identifying the location of an area but not  interested in the precise boundaries. For example, identify the location of the head in the photo of a person. The input is a photo, the output is a dot somewhere in the head. (Placing just a dot also helps during the annotation process)

Is this a (semantic) segmentation problem?

Would UNet be adequate for this?

Comment: Without knowing your input image quality, size, etc., I suspect that your best bet is to try it out on the data you have.

Comment: @Peter K. the images have good quality and resolution.